# PowerApp -> Data Connector -> Azure Blob Storage.. Change Name / Description

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am working in PowerApp and when adding a data connection for Azure Blob Storage.. they all appear with the same name. I have to add / remove them in order to find which one is the correct one I am using.

Where does it pull the description form? Or where can I change this so I can at least make an edit to mine to help me identify it.
[Image from PowerApp of Data Connectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP47P.png)

Unable to find where to modify the name or description of the connector

Comment: After creating a connection in the portal, you can try changing display name by editing the connection again.